is $P(A|B) = P(A|B \cap C)+P(A|B \cap C^{c})$?
Please note that P is a probability function. What I need to get is $P(I)$, and I already know that $F \cup F^{c}$ is a partition of $I$. So by total probability:
\begin{equation}
P(I)=P(I|F)P(F)+P(I|F^{c})P(F^c)
\end{equation}
What I have is values for $P(I|F)$ and $ P(F)$. The problem is that $F^c$ is partitioned by $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$, so I think I can get $P(I)$ using total probability again:
\begin{equation}
P(I)=P(I|F)P(F)+(P(I|F^c \cap V_1)+P(I|F^c \cap V_2))P(F^c)
\end{equation}
Is this last equation true?
Thank you in advice.

Take $B=C$ ($P(A)>0$) to get a  counter-example.

Just referring to the header question (not sure what $I$ is nor what the question in the body of your post is):  suppose $A$ is certain.  Then your equality would tell us that $1=1+1$.

Thank you both. I see it clearly

The law of total probability applied to events $A$ and $B$ is
$$\Pr[A] = \Pr[A \mid B]\color{red}{\Pr[B]} + \Pr[A \mid \bar B]\color{red}{\Pr[\bar B]};$$ that is to say, we must weight the conditional probabilities of $A$ given the partition $\{B, \bar B\}$ by the probabilities of those events occurring.
By extension, conditioning upon a third event $C$ would imply
$$\Pr[A \mid B] = \Pr[A \mid B \cap C]\color{red}{\Pr[C]} + \Pr[A \mid B \cap \bar C]\color{red}{\Pr[\bar C]}.$$

Shouldn't that last line be $$\Pr[A \mid B] = \Pr[A \mid B \cap C]\color{red}{\Pr[C|B]} + \Pr[A \mid B \cap \bar C]\color{red}{\Pr[\bar C|B]}\ ?$$
